# use dplyr to combine columns of data.frame when column names are not known

Tags: r, select, dplyr, tibble

Given a tibble:

```
library(tibble)
myTibble <- tibble(a = letters[1:3], b = c(T, F, T), c = 1:3)
```

I can use `transmute` to paste the columns, separated by '.':

```
> library(dplyr)
> transmute(myTibble, concat = paste(a, b, c, sep = "."))
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  concat   
  <chr>    
1 a.TRUE.1 
2 b.FALSE.2
3 c.TRUE.3
```

If I want to use the above `transmute` statement in a function that receives a tibble, I won't know the names of the tibble or the number of columns ahead of time.  What dplyr syntax would allow me to `paste` all columns in a tibble separated by a '.'?

Please note, I can do this with something like:

```
> apply(myTibble, 1, paste, collapse = ".")
[1] "a.TRUE.1"  "b.FALSE.2" "c.TRUE.3"
```

but I am trying to understand dplyr better.  So, yes, this is a specific problem I am trying to solve, but I am also stumped as to why I can't solve it with dplyr, which means there is something key about dplyr column selection I don't yet understand, and I'd like to learn, so that is why I'm asking specifically about a dplyr solution.

Comment: `tidyr::unite(myTibble, concat, everything())`

Comment: If you need the dots, you can enable `sep` like this `tidyr::unite(myTibble, concat, everything(),sep='.')`

Comment: It's `base`, not `dplyr`, but you could also use `do.call(paste, myTibble, sep = ".")`

Comment: The `do.call` solution is `do.call(paste, c(myTibble, list(sep = ".")))`.  Again, part of my question here is to try to understand more about selection of columns using dplyr.  If someone can tell me not just how to select all columns, but also describe why whatever solution works, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little trial and error:

```
colNames_as_symbols <- syms(names(myTibble))
transmute(myTibble, concat = paste(!!!colNames_as_symbols, sep = '.'))
```

Here was the hint that put me on to the solution...  From the documentation for `!!!`:

> The big-bang operator !!! forces-splice a list of objects. The
> elements of the list are spliced in place, meaning that they each
> become one single argument.
>
> ```
> vars <- syms(c("height", "mass"))
> ```
>
> Force-splicing is equivalent to supplying the elements separately:
>
> ```
> starwars %>% select(!!!vars)
> starwars %>% select(height, mass)
> ```

In fact, the entire documentation entitled "Force parts of an expression" is fascinating reading.  It can be accessed by issuing `?qq_show`